# Как в сишной строке заменить точку с запятой на двоеточие?

Tags: c

Дана строка. В строке заменить точку с запятой на двоеточие.

Имеется код:

```
# include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
    char s [30],
    sl [30];
    int i,n = 0,
    k = 0;
    printf ("vvedite stroku: ");
    gets (s);
    for (i=0; i<strlen(s); i++){
        if (s[i]==';');
    }
    getch();
}
```

Что нужно дописать, чтобы заменялась на двоеточие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (s[i]==';') s[i]=':';
```

Comment: не работет(

Comment: Как проверяли?

Comment: ну как, взял и провелил..

Comment: puts(s); перед getch()  пробовали ?

Comment: Я тоже проверял, и у меня работает:

    1 #include <string.h>
    2 #include <stdio.h>
    3 main () {
    4  char s[30], sl[30];
    5  int i, n = 0, k = 0;
    6 
    7  printf ("vvedite stroku: ");
    8  gets (s);
    9  for (i=0; i < strlen(s); i++ ){
    10   if (s[i]==';') s[i] = ':';
    11  }
    12  getchar();
    13 }
    (gdb) b 12
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484db: file 64543.c, line 12.
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: ./64543 
    vvedite stroku: abc;def

    Breakpoint 1, main () at 64543.c:12
    12  getchar();
    (gdb) x/s s
    0xbffff4c6:  "abc:def"
    (gdb) _

Comment: Просто чтобы увидеть результат его нужно вывести на нкран и выполнить задержку программы, как было сказано выше.